# Choose library for video streaming

Tags: web, webrtc, twilio, tokbox, videochat

I am currently developing a web app (using Spring MVC) in which I want to add 1 vs 1 video calls. I know [webRTC](https://webrtc.org/)  and many APIs based on that like: [twilio](https://www.twilio.com/video),
[tokbox](https://tokbox.com/), [agora io](https://www.agora.io/en/) etc.

What should I use? Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is 
seeking recommendations for books, tools, or software libraries.
This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an article you might find useful which details the different options and talks about whether you should build your own solution or use a platform like TokBox.
https://www.chriskranky.com/build-vs-buy-your-webrtc-services/